# Mistake position of some elements in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I make this [website](http://hmahdavi.zgig.ir/#fh5co-about-us) but have a problem. When I test the site for tablet or mobile devices position of   About us image is mistake. of course this image displayed currently in chrome but in ff no .Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Website , there is a problem with markup that's why its happened.

Replace with my markup of about section hope it will be work.
Take a look in your about us section markup and newly added markup.

Problem you firstly called a `container` and `row` for about us section in this `container` you include `col-md-12`,`col-md-8`,`col-md-4` but its not a valid markup for **bootstrap**.You can call two `row` one is include `col-md-12` and other `row` include `col-md-8`,`col-md-4` then it will perfectly work.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-bottom-padded-lg inverse animated" id="about-us">
    <div class="col-md-12 section-heading text-center ">
      <h2 class="to-animate fadeInUp animated">About Us</h2>
      <!--    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 to-animate">
                            <h3>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts.</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 to-animate fadeInUp animated">
      <img src="images/Sahand-Industrial-Group-Site_1400_638.jpg" class="img-responsive  img" alt="Free HTML5 Template">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 to-animate fadeInUp animated">
      <h2>sahand Industrial Group</h2>
      <p>Sahand Industrial Group with using of world last technology and worldwide highest quality has started to produce variety of white and color glasses such as float, patterned, reinforced, mirror, etc... And regarding its exclusive facilities is able
        to produce reinforced patterned glass too.</p>
      <p>Sahand Industrial Group includes the following factories which are acting in field of glass production and related processes.</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Azar Glass Industrial Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Mirror Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Jam Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Imeni Ark Tabriz</li>
        <li>Sahand Silica Tabriz</li>
        <li>Semnan Soda Ash Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Float Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Frough Tranbar Transport Company</li>

      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="team">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row row-bottom-padded-lg">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/azarGlass-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive  img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Azar Glass Industry Company</div>
            <p>
              Sahand Jame Tabriz Company : producer of types of white and color patterned glasses in variety of design and sizes Nominal capacity: 200 tons per day Full description of the production method: Glass rolling method; this means that melt is poured in the
              middle of two rollers, then molten rollers is rolled, so design of bottom rollers are engraved on the glass bar.
            </p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/sig-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Sahand Mirror Company</div>
            <p>This line which its technology belongs to Italy has production capacity of 5000 sq.m. in day includes 2 models: Wrinkles two-layers of and simple two-layers. Produced mirrors in addition to prepare domestic consumption, is exported to Turkey,
              Armenia and etc.</p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/sig-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Sahand Jame Tabriz Company</div>
            <p>
              Azar Glass Industry Company: Producer of flat glass and mirror in thickness of 12-3 mm and variety sizes. Nominal capacity: 350 tons per day (96000 tons per year) Full description of the production method: Producing flat glasses with the float method;
              in the way that the produced melt from raw materials by furnace with temperature of about 1530 °C is guided on melt tin and after forming is ready for cutting and remove.
            </p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**New Markup:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-bottom-padded-lg inverse animated" id="about-us">
    <div class="col-md-12 section-heading text-center ">
      <h2 class="to-animate fadeInUp animated">About Us</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 to-animate fadeInUp animated">
      <img src="images/Sahand-Industrial-Group-Site_1400_638.jpg" class="img-responsive  img" alt="Free HTML5 Template">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 to-animate fadeInUp animated">
      <h2>sahand Industrial Group</h2>
      <p>Sahand Industrial Group with using of world last technology and worldwide highest quality has started to produce variety of white and color glasses such as float, patterned, reinforced, mirror, etc... And regarding its exclusive facilities is able
        to produce reinforced patterned glass too.</p>
      <p>Sahand Industrial Group includes the following factories which are acting in field of glass production and related processes.</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Azar Glass Industrial Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Mirror Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Jam Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Imeni Ark Tabriz</li>
        <li>Sahand Silica Tabriz</li>
        <li>Semnan Soda Ash Company</li>
        <li>Sahand Float Tabriz Company</li>
        <li>Frough Tranbar Transport Company</li>

      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row animated" id="team">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row row-bottom-padded-lg">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse fadeInUp animated">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/azarGlass-logo.jpg" class="img-responsive  img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Azar Glass Industry Company</div>
            <p>
              Sahand Jame Tabriz Company : producer of types of white and color patterned glasses in variety of design and sizes Nominal capacity: 200 tons per day Full description of the production method: Glass rolling method; this means that melt is poured in the
              middle of two rollers, then molten rollers is rolled, so design of bottom rollers are engraved on the glass bar.
            </p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse fadeInUp animated">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/sig-2.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Sahand Mirror Company</div>
            <p>This line which its technology belongs to Italy has production capacity of 5000 sq.m. in day includes 2 models: Wrinkles two-layers of and simple two-layers. Produced mirrors in addition to prepare domestic consumption, is exported to Turkey,
              Armenia and etc.</p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center to-animate inverse fadeInUp animated">
          <div class="person">
            <img src="images/sig-3.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded img" alt="Person">

            <div class="position">Sahand Jame Tabriz Company</div>
            <p>
              Azar Glass Industry Company: Producer of flat glass and mirror in thickness of 12-3 mm and variety sizes. Nominal capacity: 350 tons per day (96000 tons per year) Full description of the production method: Producing flat glasses with the float method;
              in the way that the produced melt from raw materials by furnace with temperature of about 1530 °C is guided on melt tin and after forming is ready for cutting and remove.
            </p>
            <ul class="social social-circle">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```